# Send keystrokes to a specific text input if not captured by any other input

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to emulate the behavior of apps like Discord, where you can type into the message box even if it isn't focused. I'd like to do this only if no other input on the page is focused.

I tried immediately focusing the MessageBox input on blur, but this traps focus in MessageBox doesn't let me type into any other input on the page.

```
function MessageBox() {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  return <input ref={inputRef} onBlur={() => inputRef.current?.focus()} />;
}
```

Comment: Listen for key strokes in on the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on @Mina's answer, here's what I ended up doing with React:

```
function MessageBox() {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    function handler() {
      const focusedElement = document.activeElement;
      if (
        focusedElement?.tagName.toLowerCase() === "input" &&
        focusedElement?.id !== "messagebox"
      ) {
        // do nothing
      } else {
        inputRef.current?.focus();
      }
    }

    window.addEventListener("keydown", handler);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("keydown", handler);
  }, []);

  return <input ref={inputRef} id="messagebox" />;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to add an `keydown` event listener to the `window` and inside check if the `document.activeElement` ( which is the `focused` element ) tag name not an `input`, if yes, then focus the `textarea`

```js
const textarea = document.querySelector('#textarea');

window.addEventListener('keydown', () => {
  const focusedElement = document.activeElement
  if (focusedElement.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'input') {
    textarea.focus()
  }
})
```

```css
input {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen to the key event from the window.

```
const MessageBox = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    const onKeyDown = e => {
      if (e.key === 'Enter') {
        return
      }
      if (e.key === 'Backspace') {
        return
      }
      
      // consloe.log(e) to see other options  
      setValue(v => v + e.code)
    }

    window.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown)
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown)
    }
  }, [])

  const onChange = e => { setValue(e.target.value) }

  return <input value={value} onChange={onChange} />
}
```

So basically you have two ways to change the `value`, one from old `onChange` and one from the key event from now on.